# values of variables to add in an array after I click the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

how can I place the value of a variable in an array after I click the submit button? The submit button will the one to trigger the arrayholder.push().

Variables that should be added to the array are those buttons that is clicked.

JAVASCRIPT

```
qty1=0;
qty2=0;
qty3=0;
qty4=0;
arrayholder=new Array();

$("#id1").click(function(){
qty1=qty1+1;
$("#status").html(qty1);
});

$("#id2").click(function(){
qty2=qty2+1;
$("#status").html(qty2);
});

$("#id3").click(function(){
qty3=qty3+1;
$("#status").html(qty3);
});

$("#id4").click(function(){
qty4=qty4+1;
$("#status").html(qty4);
});
```

HTML CODE

```
    <button id="id1">ADD 1 QUANTITY FROM id1</button>
    <button id="id2">ADD 1 QUANTITY FROM id2</button>
    <button id="id3">ADD 1 QUANTITY FROM id3</button>
    <button id="id4">ADD 1 QUANTITY FROM id4</button>

<div id="status"></div>
<input type="submit" />
```

Comment: Instead of using `qty1=qty1+1;`, use `qty1++;`. It means "Increment `qt1` with 1".

Comment: @GeenHenk, but how can I add it to an array but first I must determine if the button was clicked. And the result will be added to the array after I clicked the submit button.

Comment: Do you only want to add to the array if the Variable Value has changed? For example only if qty1 is not 0 any more?

Comment: @SajunaFernando. YES!!

Comment: I need to check if the qty value is not 0 anymore. that's the time that I will add it to the array, after I clicked the submit button.

Comment: Check my answer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I it possible that, I can determine the sequence of clicks before I add it to the array? for instance, I first clicked the qty4 before qty3. So, I need to add qty4 to the array first then followed by qty3. And another scenario. I first clicked the qty4 before qty3. So, I need to add qty4 to the array first then followed by qty3.And I clicked the qty4 again. But previously qty4 was clicked first before qty3, so qty4 must come in the array first.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having input of type "submit", change it to type "button" and then:

```
<input id="abc" type="button" click="pushMe" />

function pushMe()
{
  arrayholder.push(qty1);
  document.getElementById("form1").submit();
}
```

Comment: I need determine the sequence of clicks before I add it to the array? for instance, I first clicked the qty4 before qty3. So, I need to add qty4 to the array first then followed by qty3. And another scenario. I first clicked the qty4 before qty3. So, I need to add qty4 to the array first then followed by qty3.And I clicked the qty4 again. But previously qty4 was clicked first before qty3, so qty4 must come in the array first. @GregOks

Comment: So the first click is what counts? if you click 4 and then 3 and then 4 again and then 3 again. it will still be 4 and then 3 in the array? Meaning, only the first click counts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click',function(){
    arrayholder.push(qty1,qty2,qty3,qty4);
    console.log(arrayholder);
    return false;
});
```

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/ymb34/)

To **distinguish** the `button count` you can `push` `key-value pairs` like

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function () {
    arrayholder.push({'qty1':qty1,'qty2':qty2,'qty3':qty3,'qty4':qty4});
    console.log(arrayholder);
    return false;
});
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/ymb34/1/)

Comment: But how can I determine if the button was clicked? And the buttons that I clicked are the only one that should be added to the array, not the whole variables.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do this?

```
$("#id1").click(function(){
    arrayholder.push(qty1++)
});
```

This will push the value to array when you click the button.

Comment: But i need to push it after I click the submit button. SO that I can determine which button is clicked. And only the clicked button iwll be added to the array.

Comment: Do you want to find which button was clicked?

Comment: Do you want to do like @sajuna Fernando did?

Comment: yes sir.. and also, I need to determine the sequence of clicks.

Comment: And can I determine the sequence of clicks before I add it to the array? for instance, I first clicked the qty4 before qty3. So, I need to add qty4 to the array first then followed by qty3. And another scenario. I first clicked the qty4 before qty3. So, I need to add qty4 to the array first then followed by qty3.And I clicked the qty4 again. But previously qty4 was clicked first before qty3, so qty4 must come in the array first.

Comment: The solution that i've given will add the values sequentially but not on submit. If you want to do so, you've to maintain an array to get the sequence of buttons and on submit you have to loop the array and get the values of the variables and push it to the result array

Comment: @marikkaniChelladurai.. Can you show me how. Coz, I'm been trying to do that, even before I posted this question. And I still failed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I guess check if the variable value has changed?

```
<input id="submitButton" type="button" click="submitForm" />

function submitForm()
{

  if(qty1 != 0){ arrayholder.push(qty1); }
  if(qty2 != 0){ arrayholder.push(qty2); }
  if(qty3 != 0){ arrayholder.push(qty3); }
  if(qty4 != 0){ arrayholder.push(qty4); }

  document.getElementById("form1").submit();
}
```

Comment: I think this must be the answer. I need to check first if the value is already change. But can I determine the sequence of clicks before I add it to the array? for instance, I first clicked the qty4 before qty3. So, I need to add qty4 to the array first then followed by qty3.

Comment: And another scenario. I first clicked the qty4 before qty3. So, I need to add qty4 to the array first then followed by qty3.And I clicked the qty4 again. But previously qty4 was clicked first before qty3, so qty4 must come in the array first.

Comment: Sorry but i dont think thats possible my friend. I confused my self thinking you wanted the one thats clicked the most to appear on top in which case you just need to sort the array.. To do what you say you will need to add to the array at the point of click. Javascript does not allow Variables to hold Variable names so i cannot think of a proper way to do this

Comment: Ohh I see.. But still, your idea helps me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

look at this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/GWAw4/2/

```
$(".TheBtn").click(function() {
   $(this).find("span").text(+$(this).find("span").text()+1); 
});


$("#submit").click(function() {
     var arrayholder = [];
     $.each($(".TheBtn"),function() {
           arrayholder.push(+$(this).find("span").text());
     });
    console.log(arrayholder);
});
```

hope it does what you want :)
check console for your array result!

Comment: let me check it first.. :)

Comment: its awesome but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I need determine the sequence of clicks before I add it to the array? for instance, I first clicked the qty4 before qty3. So, I need to add qty4 to the array first then followed by qty3. And another scenario. I first clicked the qty4 before qty3. So, I need to add qty4 to the array first then followed by qty3.And I clicked the qty4 again. But previously qty4 was clicked first before qty3, so qty4 must come in the array first.

Answer (score -3):

Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and add to it a click listener.

Push the value in the array and then submit the form with `submit()` function.

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
    //YOUR CODE HERE
    ....
    document.getElementById("yourform").submit();
});
```

Comment: But I need to click the submit button first before I add it to the array.

Comment: Submit or button doesnt matter if you want to submit a form. Submit is beter IMO.

Comment: Tell me please why the negative votes when all the people are posting my same answer....

Comment: Your explaining how to submit the form on a click event handler. Not the question that is asked. The question is how to push the values on to the array if the specific variables have been set or in other words only if the button was clicked.

Comment: @Sajuna Fernando to me the question is about how to push values before form is submitted, not how to push the values in the array, however it's ok, thank for the explanation